# How to insert signature image into PDF file in Swift?

Tags: html, swift, string, pdf, uiimage

I'm adding signature through a **SwiftSignatureView** and it give us UIImage. How can I add it in to **PDF** file? Here is my code,

```
func convertToPdfFileAndShare(){
    
    let imageData = sigImage!.pngData() ?? nil
    let base64String = imageData?.base64EncodedString() ?? ""
    
    let fmt = UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter(markupText: "&nbsp; \(ShowPDFVC.condition)</h1><h1>Signature:</h1><p>&nbsp;</p><br></div><div><br><html><body><p></p><p><b><img src='data:image/png;base64,\(String(describing: base64String))'></b></p></body></html><br><br>")
```

"sigImage" is signature image.

Answer (score 0):

you could try this approach to write your signature to a pdf file:

```
if let theImage = sigImage, let pdfPage = PDFPage(image: theImage) {
    let doc = PDFDocument()
    pdfPage.setBounds(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: theImage.size.width, height: theImage.size.height), for: .mediaBox)
    doc.insert(pdfPage, at: 0)
    // write the pdf document to file
    writeToFile(doc, file: "test")
}
        
func writeToFile(_ doc: PDFDocument, file: String) {
    do {
        let dir = try FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
        let fileURL = dir.appendingPathComponent(file).appendingPathExtension("pdf")
        doc.write(to: fileURL)
    } catch {
        print("\(error)")
    }
}
```